# How does it matter to be an apple membership developer of different regions?

Tags: ios, iphone-developer-program

Does it make any difference to apply for an apple membership developer with a U.S.A credit card & U.S.A contact address or with some other country credit card & address (let's say China)? Is it of more opportunity for the app created by the U.S.A registered developer to be featured in the U.S.A appstore?

Comment: can be .. no one reveals trade secrets. the question is not fit for stackoverflow btw

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about General App Store distribution program rather than programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no it doesnt matter where you got your account.. or rather... it shouldnt :D

Only some folks at apple could tell you and as Kabira said:
"no one reveals trade secrets."